# Нужны ли превьюшки в фотогалерее?

Tags: изображения

Есть фотогалерея, первоначально картинки показываются в уменьшеном варианте, при клике открываются в полный размер.

Вопрос: нужно ли сохранять два варианта изображения - полноразмерное и миниатюру? Или можно обойтись одним?

---

Поясню мысль, если кто не понял.
Есть ли смысл сохранять два изображения? Что лучше с технической точки зрения ? Что удобнее для пользователей?
На мой взгляд, единственный плюс варианта с миниатюрами - они быстрее загрузтся, если интернет медленный.

Answer (score 3):

Задача - хранить для галереии оригинал и две отрисовки картинка мини-превьюшку. И большую, которую показываем при клике, её выравниваем под одинаковый размер, возможно накладываем ватермарк.

Давайте по пунктам.

Плюсы:

- картинка имеет маленький размер, поэтому быстро грузится;
- картинка кешируется у клиента и серверным прокси - уменьшается нагрузка на сервер и каналы;
- картинка не вызывает нагрузку на сервер при каждом обращении к ней. Если оригиналы картинок сняты на фотик 10-15 Мп (что на самом деле бывает у клиентов сплошь и рядом) - нагрузка на сервер может быть очень нихреновая;
- гарантированное качество отображения картинки у клиента.

Минусы:

- затрачивается место на веб-хостинге.

Исходя из того, что в 90% случаев:

- средний сайт занимает неболее 20% места выделяемого хостером;
- размер оригинала фото 1-1.5Мб, а размер превьюшек 1-5Кб, а большой картинка 70-120Кб... То на общем фоне это даже как-то теряется;

То в большинстве случаев смысл в этом есть.

Answer (score 0):

Например с помощью Fancybox:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.gallery').fancybox({
        prevEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'none',
        closeBtn: false,
        arrows: false,
        nextClick: true,
        helpers: {
          thumbs: {
            width: 50,
            height: 50
          }
        }
      });
 });

<a class="gallery" href="/1.jpg">
  <img src="/1.jpg" width="220px" height="200px" />
</a>

<a class="gallery" href="/2.jpg">
  <img src="/2.jpg" width="220px" height="200px" />
</a>
```

В блоке `helpers` - настройки thumbnails

Comment: Это не совсем то. Мне интересно не как отображать картинки, а есть ли смысл хранить в два раза больше изображений.

Comment: да, видимо не так понял вопрос. ок, лично я не считаю что сейчас необходимо при разработке акцентировать внимание на то, что у юзера может быть медленный интернет. 2013 год все-таки. Тогда, есстественно, логичнее хранить один набор полноразмерных картинок, и работать с ними.

Comment: @Макс Жуков, а на пользователей мобильных устройств забьём, хоть скорость подключения там не такая шустрая. Пусть мимо проходят или выкидывают свои мобильники ;)

Comment: Вот это единственный повод хранить превьюшки.
Другой вопрос. А так ли часто пользователям мобильников нужно смотреть фотографии? А если часто нужно, то скорее всего у них инет пошустрее.

Comment: @oleg_ismaylov, вы сказали, что у вас есть раздел фотогалерея. То есть, человека, пройдя на данную страничку, могут и не интересовать фотографии? А вообще, если у вас жесткая нехватка дискового пространства, тогда можно и ограничиться одной оригинальной копией фото. Сейчас, ради интереса, глянул сколько превьюшек у одного моего клиента и сколько вся эта папка весит: 3669 миниатюрок, 8.18 Мб. Много? Или влом запустить скриптик при загрузке фото, чтоб сделать превьюшку?

Comment: @Deonis, те, у кого мобильники, на которых имеет смысл смотреть фотогалерею, явно подключаются либо по wi-fi, либо с безлимиткой. даже на мтс 300 руб. в месяц.

Comment: Я, например, если и захожу на сайты с мобильника, то чаще чтобы посмотреть адрес или телефон или еще что-нибудь подобное. В крайнем случае посмотреть сообщения в контакте.
Какой смысл смотреть фотографии на малентком экране?

Answer (score 0):

Определенно есть смысл, если изображение большие. Если у вас как в инстаграм они 400 на 400 то смысла я не вижу.

Comment: Это логичное и достаточно очевидное решение. Но, в том то и дело, что фотографии средненькие. Скажем, не больше 500px в высоту.